# How to get line chart to show 3 columns from CSV files?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i have a CSV file showcasing the reduction of Methane in the atmosphere from the UK over a 9 year period. I'm attempting to get the file to show the data visually while using matplotlib, later on, I hope to add more countries to the script so that I can showcase how counties have reduced their emissions throughout the years, but I can't seem to get the output to look quite right?

The script is functioning as expected but when I run the output it's showing each entry as one single output, so instead of showing a chart with a positive correlation, it's showcasing a single entry showcasing all of the results at once. Please see the attached code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\avalo\Desktop\Data.csv')
print (df)

X = list(df.iloc[:, 0])
Y = list(df.iloc[:, 1])

plt.plot(X, Y, color='b')
plt.title("Levels of Methane (CH4) Emissions (Tonnes)")
plt.xlabel("Years")
plt.ylabel("Number of Tonnes")

plt.show()
```

It then shows this output:

[image]

The CSV file looks as follows:

[image]

Ideally, I would like it so that the line could be one colour so that I could add other data entries to the original CSV file and then into the script as different colours to better visualise the difference. Any and all help on this would be great! Thanks.

Comment: I think it might be from having 3 columns within the CSV, removing the "Country or Area" column produced a correct line chart. However I don't see how this would resolve it, as when I need to add more counties to the original CSV, as well as making them appear in different colours, I'm still stumped.

Comment: You need seaborn. `sns.lineplot(data=df, x='year', y='levels of ...', hue='country')`. With only matplotlib you're in for a lot of work mimicking seaborn.

Answer (score 0):

You could reformat your dataframe after reading your csv and put the countryname into the columnname (Multiindex). This way you can plot multiple states against one time column in one plots with different colors using Dataframe.plot(x='Year'). I didnt test the pandas plot function, but this was my code to rearrange your dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce



data = [['UK', 2019, 10000],['UK', 2018, 20000],['GER', 2019, 10000],['GER', 2018, 30000]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['country','Year', 't/a'])

grouped = df.groupby('country')

dflist = []

for name, group in grouped:
    group.drop('country', 1 , inplace=True)
    group.columns = ['Year', f'{name} t/a']
    group.sort_values(by=['Year'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
    dflist.append(group)
    
dffinal = reduce(lambda df1,df2: pd.merge(df1,df2,on='Year'), dflist)
```

If you get different files for each country you can drop the groupby and just read each file inside the for loop and do the reformating.
Sadly im not on a machine with python installed right now and the online ide couldnt handle df.plot somehow, but the pandas plot function is well documented on their website: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html?highlight=plot
`dffinal.plot(x='Year',y=[all columnames here])`  will probably give you a decent result